# Appscript data collection

Tags: javascript, html, web, payfast

I want my form (html) to submit to appscript and after a successful submission i want the form to submit to payfast to process a payment based on the info in the form.

I managed to make it submit to appscript but it took me to a success page not submitting to payfast

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.